# Rotating an object around any origin

Tags: trigonometry

I want to extend my [program that generates PDF](http://speedata.github.io/publisher/index.html) and I need like to rotate an object (for example -30deg clockwise):

[image: basic rotation]

*1: original 2: rotated object (origin is bottom left)*

The first problem is, that the software can only rotate at the top left edge, so that I need move the resulting object:

[image]

*The next step is to move 2 down so that it looks, as if the object is rotated around the bottom left edge*

The second problem is, that the origin can be at any place inside the bounding boxes of the object, for example at 90% to the right and 20% to the bottom, similar to this:

[image]

**Question**

How can I calculate the movement in x and y direction?

[image]

*(this is another angle as in the examples above)*

That is: I have object number 1, rotate it around the left top edge (object 2, no problem yet), but I need to find the vector (black arrows) that moves the object 2 to get to object 3.

Manually I'd move the resulting object so that the origin of 2 is on the horizontal axis of the origin of 1:

[image]

So that I now have this situation ...

[image]

... and then horizontally towards the origin of the original object:

[image]

and voila, I have the result I need.

Now I need to express the shifting in terms of sin and cos, to do that programmatically.

I guess it is not feasible to ask for a solution, so I humbly ask for a hint, how to start. I do know basic trigonometry, but somehow my brain blocks.

Comment: ... my math seems to be too low level to understand the answers. It will take some time until I will understand them and I'll report back!

Answer (score 1):

Any planar rigid motion can be represented by a rotation about the origin (or any other reference point) followed by a translation:
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb R^2&\to\mathbb R^2, \\
p&\mapsto Rp+t.
\end{split}
$$
where 
$$
R=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{array}
\right], t\in\mathbb R^2.
$$
This map becomes a linear map under the homogeneous representation:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
p\\
1
\end{array}
\right]\mapsto \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
R&t\\
0&1
\end{array}
\right]\cdot\left[
\begin{array}{c}
p\\
1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
So a pure rotation about the origin is given by:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
R&0\\
0&1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
If a different reference point, say $q\in\mathbb R^2$ is chosen, the corresponding transformation matrix is given by:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
R&(I-R)q\\
0&1
\end{array}
\right]=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I&q\\
0&1
\end{array}
\right]\cdot \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
R&0\\
0&1
\end{array}
\right]\cdot \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I&-q\\
0&1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Intuitively, you move the reference point $q$ to the origin, performs the rotation, and move it back. This is called a conjugation operation. The resulting rotation group is a conjugate group of the group of rotation about the origin.

Comment: What is $I$ in the last equation?

Comment: @topskip I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In coordinates where the rotating point is at $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}=O$

A rotation in 2d can be expressed by a rotational matrix $M\in SO(2)$
$$M(\phi)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi&-\sin\phi\\\sin\phi&\cos\phi\end{pmatrix}$$

so the rotated coordinate is
$$p\to p'=M(\phi)p$$

Thus movement therefore is $p-p'=\left(1-M(\phi)\right)p$

Answer (score 0):

Some related hints from vector analysis:

1. Find co-ordinates of each corner and position vectors in $ x + i y $ complex vector form.
2. Multiply each position vector by $e^{i \alpha} $ where $\alpha$ is angle through which entire object is to be rotated.
3. Edge vectors are position vector differences.
4. If any translation is required add a constant vector $ a + i b $.